# pgAdmin 4 won't accept blank password

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I hope this doesn't appear as a duplicate question, but every answer I see suggests changing the hba file or something, that seems to assume postgres is running from my machine. I'm running postgres inside of a Docker container that I have no control over.

`psql -U <username>` doesn't have any issue connecting though from inside of the container (and doesn't prompt for a password).

I might just be missing something simple, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth checking to see if there's a `PGPASSWORD` environment variable where you're running `psql` from - if there is `psql` uses that without prompting. Otherwise you might need to clarify what you mean by "won't accept blank password" - e.g. do you get the `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` error or something else?

Comment: Thanks for this, @GregHNZ ... I don't know why I didn't check env before. `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` was actually the one set.